# how use shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat in web "@tensorflow/tfjs"

Tags: html, tensorflow.js

how use shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat  in web "@tensorflow/tfjs"

js code example?

thanks

I don't know

1. How to convert it to web tfjs format
2. I don't know how to use it in web tfjs yet

I search google, but can not resuts
https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=how+convert+shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat+tfjs&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8